# Binding a long list of POST data whose names do not match the COLUMN names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 100 questions whose input names are:

```
name="one"
name="two" etc...
```

The table I am using has columns

```
q1--|--q2--|--q3--|..etc...
```

is there a slick way of looping the post data to bind it to the proper column names?

I dont want to do this:

```
$sth->bindParam(':q1', $_POST['one']);
```

The answers i have seen are for POST whose keys correspond to the column names and I can not change the form names as it is out of my control.

Answer (score -1):

The [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method can take an `array` where the name of the binding is the key, and the values are set accordingly. This is a lot easier than repeated `bindParam` calls:

```
$sth->execute(array(':q1' => $_POST['one'], ...));
```